# What is a quasi-isomorphism of two crossed modules

Tags: homology

Could you tell me how are two crossed modules quasi-isomorphic. 
And I have known a result:
Let $\mu: M \rightarrow G$ and $\mu': M' \rightarrow G'$ are isomorphic, then the integral homology of them are the same.
How to prove this result?

Could you show me related materials?

Thanks,

Comment: Please see the FAQ, in particular what sort of questions are appropriate for MO. 

Comment: In particular, I believe this question would be better placed at http://math.stackexchange.com (and please read their FAQ before posting there)

Comment: I'm sorry. It was the first time I posted my question. I will see FAQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even if David Roberts is right, I'll give an answer; more details my be found in the book

R. Brown, P.J. Higgins, R. Sivera,  *Nonabelian algebraic
topology: filtered spaces, crossed complexes, cubical homotopy
groupoids*, EMS Tracts in Mathematics Vol. 15, 703 pages. (August
2011).

of which a pdf may be downloaded from

http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html

Any crossed module $\mu: M \to P$ has a classifying space $X=B(\mu)$ whose homotopy groups are 0 above dimension 2 and in dimensions 1 and 2 are respectively Coker $\mu$ and Ker $\mu$. A morphism $f$ of crossed modules is a weak equivalence  iff the induced map of classifying spaces is a weak equivalence. The homology of a crossed module is defined as the homology of its classifying space.  The result asked for is easily obtained by passing to universal covers.

For more information see also

{Ellis, Graham J.},
     TITLE = {Homology of {$2$}-types},
   JOURNAL = {J. London Math. Soc. (2)},
    VOLUME = {46},
      YEAR = {1992},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {1--27},

and the subsequent correction.